# C how to print address as a decimal value (not hex) without compiler warnings

Tags: c, pointers, printf, memory-address, format-string

I have an `int` pointer that points at the address of another `int`.

When printing the pointer with the format specifier `%p` (as suggested by many answers on Stack Overflow), it's printed with a **hexadecimal** representation.

How can I print a pointer's value with with a **decimal** representation?

---

**Code Sample**

I have figured out one can maybe use `%zu` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15337836).

```c
int i = 1;
int *p = &i;
printf("Printing p: %%p = %p, %%zu = %zu\n", p, p);
```

When I run that code using https://onlinegdb.com/EBienCIJnm

- It actually prints the correct value in decimal
- *But* it also outputs a compiler warning

```
warning: format ‘%zu’ expects argument of type ‘size_t’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]                                                                 
Printing p: %p = 0x7ffee623d8c4, %zu = 140732759529668
```

Is there a way to `printf` a pointer's value with a decimal representation, without compiler warnings?

Comment: `unsigned long addr = (unsigned long)p`; `printf("Printing addr: %lu\n",addr);` any problem with this?

Comment: Yeah looks like `%lu` paired with a cast to `(unsigned long)` works as well (https://onlinegdb.com/OpOSsz6Oq).  I also like it because it doesn't require a `#include` of `<stdint.h>` and/or `<inttypes.h>` as the other answers do.  @IrAM, is this a platform-independent solution (since it requires pointers to be the size of an `unsigned long`)?  Seems from [this Quora answer](https://qr.ae/pNmnvI), it's not always the size of `unsigned long`

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the portability, but my idea is choose the longest type available based on platform, so that you can represent address properly in decimal. I guess for any platform following will be true `short <= int <= long <= long long`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert to the `uintptr_t` type defined in `<stdint.h>` and format with the `PRIuPTR` specifier defined in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) &argc);
}
```

Comment: which version of `C` this `PRIuPTR` is introduced?

Comment: @IrAM: Last millennium, C 1999.

Comment: Ohh, I came to know about it very recently!!! Does `uintptr_t` give correct values for pointers depends on platform, making it a portable solution?

Comment: @IrAM: What are “correct values”? It is pretty portable. It is optional for an implementation to provide `uintptr_t`, but most C implementations do, and, if they do, the resulting `uintptr_t` value contains all the information needed to represent the pointer. How it is encoded as an unsigned integer is implementation-defined, so that aspect is not portable. Implementations with flat address spaces generally use the address directly for the integer value. Printing it in decimal is somewhat uncommon. Addresses are more often printed in hexadecimal, which you can do with `PRIxPTR`.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the pointer to `uintmax_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`), and print the cast result with `%ju`:

```c
printf("Printing p: %%p = %p, %%ju = %ju\n", p, (uintmax_t)p);
```

Note that there is no guarantee that `uintmax_t` is wide enough to hold a pointer, but it's probably OK. (If it's not OK for your platform, the compiler might complain.) You could use `uintptr_t`, as suggested elsewhere, but in the case that `uintmax_t` isn't wide enough, `uintptr_t` won't exist at all.

On the whole, you're better off learning how to deal with hexadecimal output :-)